# How do I make a SOAP call with assertions?

Tags: node.js, soap, get, soapui, web-api-testing

How do I make a SOAP call, then assert the response status code, and assert any one node value in response XML?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
   <ns1:GetQuote xmlns:ns1="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
   <ns1:symbol>IBM</ns1:symbol>
      </ns1:GetQuote>
```

WSDL:'http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL'

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: @kalpesh if you are able to solve your problem using the solution. You can accept it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the last link in this answer to learn more

1) you can use 2 assertions (for using assertions you need to add testcase in soapui, by adding your request to test case)

1. **Valid HTTP Status codes** (you can put 200 or if you want to validate more than one you can put comma separated

[image]

2. You can use **Xpath match** where you can write the xpath and put the expected value

[image]

[Learn Assertions using this link](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html)